# Handle error from wrong path in CXF Server

Tags: java, spring, web-services, apache-camel, cxfrs

I'm trying to handle error in CXF rest service. Which i want to gain is a situation when user is trying to send request and he's choosing a wrong path. I would like to handle this situation. The default responses are:

```
2014-05-15 14:07:14 INFO  [qtp811959489-40] LoggingOutInterceptor:234 - Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 405
Content-Type: 
Headers: {Allow=[POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD], Date=[Thu, 15 May 2014 12:07:14 GMT], Content-Length=[0]}
```

My resource class:

```
@Path("payment/v1/")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class OneApiResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{endUserId}/transactions")
    public PaymentTransactionListWrapper listTransactions(@PathParam("endUserId") String endUserId) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

endpoint:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
    ">

    <bean id="jsonProviderFactory" class="model.oneApi.JsonProviderFactory"/>
    <bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
    <cxf:rsServer id="bieService"
                  address="http://{{endpoint.jetty.app.oneApi.host}}:{{endpoint.jetty.app.oneApi.service.port}}/{{endpoint.jetty.app.oneApi.service.ctx}}/"
                  loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
                  serviceClass="model.oneApi.OneApiResource"
                  loggingSizeLimit="-1"
                  skipFaultLogging="false">
        <cxf:providers>
            <bean factory-bean="jsonProviderFactory" factory-method="create"/>
        </cxf:providers>
        <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
        </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:rsServer>

</beans>
```

Is there any way to handle it?

Comment: How do you want to handle it? what is differently handle?

Comment: I just wanted to handle situation when request is sending on the resource which doesn't exist. For instance user is sending reqest on HTTP method, specific endpoint but wrong request:
/{endUserId}/sthwrong/transactions" in case of /{endUserId}/transactions". I wanted to catch it and send him an answer:
wrong path my friend!

Comment: @Marin Erbel Does your error message change dynamically?

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking more about some kind of a information which could be return to user that he was trying to post request on a wrong path of a server. For instance, there is a one method on webserver:
/pathToWebService/method
and when he is trying access to another method he should be informed about that:
"There is no method on that servlet. Try one of these : /pathToWebService/method"

Comment: hi @MarcinErbel did you find any solution to the above question?

Comment: To be honest I don’t remember well that problem, but I think that it needs cxf out interceptor in a appropriate phase :)